# Django URLs TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-1.10

After upgrading to Django 1.10, I get the error:

```
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

My urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'myapp.views.contact'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
]
```

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/alasdair/dev/urlproject/urlproject/urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.home'),
  File "/Users/alasdair/.virtualenvs/django110/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Comment: If we use decorators on view and if it do not return anything. In this case also we get above error. recently I got this error.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta yes, if a decorator does not return a view then it implicitly returns `None`, which would cause a `TypeError` as above.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Django 1.10 no longer allows you to specify views as a string (e.g. `'myapp.views.home'`) in your URL patterns.

The solution is to update your `urls.py` to include the view callable. This means that you have to import the view in your `urls.py`. If your URL patterns don't have names, then now is a good time to add one, because reversing with the dotted python path no longer works.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from myapp.views import home, contact

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
]
```

If there are many views, then importing them individually can be inconvenient. An alternative is to import the views module from your app.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from myapp import views as myapp_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', myapp_views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', myapp_views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
]
```

Note that we have used `as myapp_views` and `as auth_views`, which allows us to import the `views.py` from multiple apps without them clashing.

See the [Django URL dispatcher docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) for more information about `urlpatterns`.

Comment: What about class based views?

Comment: You've never been able to use the dotted string path for class based views, so they are not relevant to this question.

Comment: I wish to see the change like this come with some helper (a migrating script), because you are not able to use prefix as well. `import_module` could help you build own lookup as a wrapper for the old-way string, in a case when thousands of urls are waiting for you to update them.

Comment: You still have to import other packages, too - import from django.conf.urls import  url. Please fix your solution.

Comment: @WebComer I didn't include the url import in the question/answer because they remain the same when upgrading to Django 1.10 (unless you have `django.conf.urls.defaults` from Django 1.5 or earlier). I've added the imports as you asked, but I'm not sure that this is a good idea, since the imports change again in Django 2.0.  If you want to know the correct imports, then the docs for your version of Django (e.g. [1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/), [2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/)) are the best place to look.

Answer (score 3):

This error just means that `myapp.views.home` is not something that can be called, like a function. It is a string in fact. While your solution works in django 1.9, nevertheless it throws a warning saying this will deprecate from version 1.10 onwards, which is exactly what has happened. The previous solution by @Alasdair imports the necessary view functions into the script through either 
    `from myapp import views as myapp_views`    or
    `from myapp.views import home, contact`

Answer (score 2):

You may also get this error if you have a name clash of a view and a module. I've got the error when i distribute my view files under views folder, `/views/view1.py, /views/view2.py` and imported some model named table.py in view2.py which happened to be a name of a view in view1.py. So naming the view functions as  `v_table(request,id)`  helped.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you got the error on your terminal, it is possible that if you stop the server and then run it again, it would work.
On Windows:

> ```
> ctrl+c
> ```

to stop the server
then run the server again:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'myapp.views.contact'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
]
```

change it to following as you're importing `include()` function :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

change
`register = template.Library()`
to
`registerr = template.Library()`
resovled my issue