# Django Error: Your URL pattern is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

After upgrading to Django 1.10, I get the following error when I run `python manage.py runserver`:

```
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern ('^$', 'myapp.views.home') is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
HINT: Try using url() instead of a tuple.
```

My `urlpatterns` are as follows:

```
from myapp.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    (r'^$', home, name='home'),
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To simplify URL configs, `patterns()` was deprecated in Django 1.8, and removed in 1.10 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10)). In Django 1.10, `urlpatterns` must be a list of `url()` instances. Using a tuple in `patterns()` is not supported any more, and the Django checks framework will raise an error.

Fixing this is easy, just convert any tuples

```
urlpatterns = [
    (r'^$', home, name='home'),  # tuple
]
```

to `url()` instances:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),  # url instance
]
```

If you get the following `NameError`,

```
NameError: name 'url' is not defined
```

then add the following import to your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

If you use strings in your url patterns, e.g. `'myapp.views.home'`, you'll have to update these to use a callable at the same time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744285/django-urls-error-view-must-be-a-callable-or-a-list-tuple-in-the-case-of-includ) for more info.

See the [Django URL dispatcher docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) for more information about `urlpatterns`.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have used URL patterns like this:

```
urlpatterns += (
    (r'^404/$', page_not_found_view),
)
```

Change it to:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^404/$', page_not_found_view),
]
```