# How do I fix my url patterns for django 1.10.2?

Tags: python, django

This is my url pattern:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from school.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'^$', home, name = 'home') #school.views.home')

    #url(r'^$', 'main.views.home', name = 'school_home')
    url(r'^$', home, name = 'home')
]

urlpatterns = [
    #'django.contrib.auth.views',

    url(r'^login/$', 'login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name = 'school_login'),

    url(r'^logout/$', 'logout', {'next_page': 'school_home'},  name = 'school_logout'),
    ]
```

For some reason I keep getting these awful errors that just won't let my application run when I ask it to runserver.

Here is my traceback error message:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x03F292B8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in
wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374,
 in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361,
 in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81,
in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in c
heck_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in c
heck_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in ur
l_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in ur
lconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\schoolDatabase\schoolDatabase\urls.py", line 31, in
<module>
    url(r'^login/$', 'login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name = 'school_lo
gin'),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 85, in
 url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of incl
ude().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

I've had a look at other stackoverflow questions regarding the url pattern and I've tried adjusting it but it still won't work.

Can anybody help?

Comment: This is very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744285/django-urls-error-view-must-be-a-callable-or-a-list-tuple-in-the-case-of-includ?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I've answered below in case you already saw it and are still stuck.

Comment: What link? I don't see it. Can you add it with a comment please?

Answer (score 0):

Import the auth views, then change your URL patterns to use the callable.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name = 'school_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': 'school_home'},  name = 'school_logout'),
]
```