# Django - TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, django

I am using wut4lunch app from the tutorial. Here is the code:

```
 from django.conf.urls import include, url
 from django.contrib import admin
 import wut4lunch.views

 urlpatterns = [url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 url(r'^$', 'wut4lunch.views.index', name='home'),
 url(r'^newlunch', 'wut4lunch.views.newlunch', name='newlunch')
 ]
```

This code is the part of wut4lunch app mentioned in the blog:
https://www.airpair.com/python/posts/django-flask-pyramid

I have given the content of url.py. Please explain the problem

Comment: Please include the full stack trace and what version of django your using. For the latest version, you dont need to use include for the admin urls but that isnt the error

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744285/django-urls-error-view-must-be-a-callable-or-a-list-tuple-in-the-case-of-includ

Comment: You need to add your traceback !