# TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().hh

Tags: python, django

```
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

urls

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',"newhomaa.views.home", name='home'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
return render(request,"home.html",{})
```

INSTALLED_APPS
        = [

```
'newhomaa',
```

i need solv my Problem

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744285/django-urls-error-view-must-be-a-callable-or-a-list-tuple-in-the-case-of-includ

Comment: I know but I do not know what he wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the `home` function from your views, and use that in your url pattern instead of the string.

```
from newhomaa.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Note that in Django 1.9+, you do not need to use `include()` with `admin.site.urls`.