# Python Django | Importing views in urls.py

Tags: python, django

My **urls.py** looks like this :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from devicesfor import views
from devicesfor.forms import LoginForm

admin.autodiscover()

list_patterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^', include('devicesfor.urls')),
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'devicesfor/login.html'}),
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/login'}),
]

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', include(list_patterns)),
]
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

I understand that I have to import the view in your **urls.py.** Being a newbie, not super sure how I would modify the code and fit this in..

Appreciate your help!

Many thanks!!

Comment: Follow the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744285/django-urls-error-view-must-be-a-callable-or-a-list-tuple-in-the-case-of-includ

Comment: I tried the possible combinations! I did go through the sections of the link you posted even before asking the questions. I just wanted to know the corrections I have to do in my code to make it work. Thanks for your valuable time to let me know it is a duplicate, which I was totally aware of!

Comment: What is the django version you are using @  cashanzlo

Comment: My version is 1.11.2

Comment: url(r'^login/$', 'views.login', {'template_name': 'devicesfor/login.html'}),
url(r'^logout/$', 'views.logout', {'next_page': '/login'}),
]

Comment: you are already importing views

Comment: Doesn't help! :( Syntax error