# can not import patterns in django 1.11.4

Tags: python, django

My project **urls.py** is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

My app **urls.py** is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^hello/', 'myapp.views.hello', name = 'hello'),)
```

Now , as soon as I try to run it , it gives me the following error:

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns'
```

Comment: depending on your version of django you might need `from django.conf.urls.detault import patterns` instead

Comment: Note you can remove `admin.autodiscover()` in Django 1.7+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django doesn't require you to use patterns anymore, you can just make `urlpatterns` a list of urls

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'^hello/', 'myapp.views.hello', name = 'hello'),]
```

Comment: That fixes half the problem. You then need to import [replace the string `'myapp.views.hello'` with the callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744285/).

Comment: @Alasdair - Yes, thats true. Although I don't want to spoil all of the OP's research :)

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.11 loads that Python module and looks for the variable urlpatterns. This should be a Python list of django.conf.urls.url() instances.

And it runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL

Dont require `patterns` more.

`urlpatterns` should be a Python list of url() instances.