# How to setup URL.PY Code for Django 1.11 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am very new to coding and started 2 days back, and using the Ubuntu distro since yesterday. I have been following a youtube video on how to build a website using python, and in the video he is using a Mac. It has been similar for the most part, but I have been able to google the few differences and fix them on my own. I am having trouble with the code that you use for the url.py file. Images of the error have been attached.
[*The code edit I did in the text editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOEPW.png)
[*The error I get on my Ubuntu terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZreR.png)

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Current Code

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
]
```

Error When running "python manage.py runserver"

```
NameError: name 'home' is not defined
```

Comment: Include your `urls.py`.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744285/) might help.

Comment: Please don't link to screenshots. Include the code and full traceback as text in your question.

Comment: included the code in urls.py after editing from the linked question from Alasdair

Comment: There is no difference in how you write urls.py on Ubuntu or Mac.