# Having trouble with Django URLS

Tags: python, django

So I am getting the error TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Here is my code

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django URLs TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744285/django-urls-typeerror-view-must-be-a-callable-or-a-list-tuple-in-the-case-of-in)

Comment: The problem will be in views.py. You'll have to include the relevant code from there for anyone to be able to answer.

Comment: Well you see I can't create an app because of this error so it can't be connected to view.py.